# What is the time complexity of Map.prototype.size in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, time-complexity

Here's a link to the method, just trying to figure out what the time complexity is compared to doing a .length for an array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size

Comment: This is a surprisingly interesting question, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Per specification, Array [`length`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-exotic-objects) is a simple read-only data property, but Map [`size`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-get-map.prototype.size) is an accessor property that calculates the number of items by looping through the list of Map entries.

In reality, I'd expect `size` to be optimized by JavaScript engines so it doesn't have to loop through the list every time, but the loop is how the spec defines it.

So in theory the answer to *"What is the time complexity of Map.prototype.size in JavaScript?"* is O(n), but I bet the reality is much better than that.

Comment: Interesting, but when checking for the size of a user created object, you’d need to for sure iterate through the entire object for every size check right?

Comment: @mek24 - If you don't do anything to avoid it (which is possible, but a pain), yes, you would. Part of the advantage of `Map` I guess, is that you have the potential/probably benefit of optimization in the JS engine if this is information you need...